# Using chromedriver to download a generated PDF

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I am new web scraping. I am trying to use google web diver to click on a link to download the batman movie script, but I have been running into some errors.  I read somewhere that because the file is generate instead of stored on the database that it might not be possible to download it via a web scraper.  Can anyone help me?
I have the following python script on google colab:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver

download_url = 'https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/batman-begins-script-screenplay-pdf-download'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get(download_url)
button = wd.find_element_by_tag_name("Download PDF")
button.click()
wd.close()
```

Comment: I think that by showing the error type it would be helpful for understanding problem better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element matching `Download PDF` tag name on that web page.
This is why your `wd.find_element_by_tag_name("Download PDF")` code line obviously throws exception. And if not `button` will be a `NoneType` object that does not have `click()` method.